# UIView not displayed with translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints set to NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to increase the height of mainview dynamically as the content size of scrollview increases. As you see in my image, there is white space left in scrollview and I want that to be covered by my main view. I don't know initially what will be the content size of scrollview as it is increasing at runtime.

Here is my following code:

```
int x= 17;
int y = 27;
int width = 287;
int height = 181;
int mainview_height = 568;
int x_spacer = 0;
int y_spacer = 0;
int width_spacer = 320;
int height_spacer = 27;
UIView *view_spacer = [[UIView alloc]init];
[view_spacer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
view_spacer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.mainView addSubview:view_spacer];
 UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
 [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
 [self.mainView addSubview:view1];
[view_spacer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width_spacer/height_spacer constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width_spacer/mainview_height constant:0.0f]];  
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view.spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]];
[view1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width/height constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width/mainview_height constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

My view1 and view_spacer are not getting displayed. What is wrong in my code?[image: I want to increase the height of mainview dynamically as the content size of scrollview increases. As you see in my image, there is white space left in scrollview and I want that to be covered by my main view. I don't know initially what will be the content size of scrollview as it is increasing at runtime.]

Comment: Please help. What should I do so that my views get displayed?

Comment: Have you considered to use one of the many CocoaPod libraries to manage `NSLayoutConstraints`

Comment: No. I have not used any libraries to manage NSLayoutConstraints. Can you please help me and tell me which library I should use?

Comment: edit your question and post an image of how you need your screen to be displayed. That makes the question more understandable. Also you will get your result quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution. I have tried this code in a test project. Its working fine just needs a slight change. Paste below code instead of your code and check it. I have changed the second view color to red to identify better.

```
float x= 17;
float y = 27;
float width = 287;
float height = 181;
float mainview_height = 568;
float x_spacer = 0;
float y_spacer = 0;
float width_spacer = 320;
float height_spacer = 27;

UIView *view_spacer = [[UIView alloc]init];
[view_spacer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
view_spacer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.mainView addSubview:view_spacer];
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.mainView addSubview:view1];

[view_spacer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width_spacer/height_spacer constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width_spacer/mainview_height constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]];
[view1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width/height constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width/mainview_height constant:0.0f]];
[self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.mainView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: But height of self.mainView is not updated according to the scrollview content size. How can I increase the height of main view and scrollview dynamically according to content size?

Comment: i don't see any scroll view in your code and how you are using scroll view in your screen. I can guess that you should use proportional height to make the height dynamic but depends upon the requirement and also you can use aspect ratio to super view to increase views according to increment of screen size. If my answer fixed your problem then you should accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: self.mainView is the subview of scrollview. I have used aspect ratio constraints for scrollview and set top,bottom,leading and trailing constraints of self.mainView to 0. But self.mainView frame not get updated according to scrollview content size. Thanks

Comment: are you updating scroll view frame and if yes how? this matters for the changing of self.mainView frame.

Comment: can you please create a test repo in git with what you have done and provide a screenshot of what you required with comments in the screenshot.

Comment: yes I have tried updated scrollview frame by using self.scrollview setFrame = (CGRect){CGPointZero, self.scrollView.contentSize};

Comment: you are using constraints so first thing is you cannot update frame just like that otherwise it will give constraint error logs and second thing is the way you are changing the frame like of its content size its also not correct. Am not clear till now what exactly you need with scroll view. Please update question with screenshots or ask new question or provide test project.

Comment: I am not able to post image. But I have updated my question. May be it may clear my requirements.

Comment: I have posted the image. I hope now it will clear my requirements.

Comment: why you are increasing the content size of the scroll view. you don't need that. just take the mainview and scrollview and give equal height and top from mainview to scrollview and bottom from mainview to scrollview. Your white space will not be there after those changes.

Comment: I am increasing the content size of scrollview because my subview of main view is created dynamically and they can be of any number.

Comment: don't increase the content size. just configure those things with constraints when you are creating this view. add constraints like i said in previous comment.

Comment: It would be a great help if u explain it with the help of demo.

Comment: add a repo on Github with sample project of what you did. just a view controller and other stuff and i will edit with the result what you need.

Comment: You can find sample project from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GbdFwoUdh5Y25VY1FyVEZTUjg/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: your code is indicating that you want to take the smaller view inside the scrollview to be height of 181 then how it will cover the whole screen?

Comment: I want my main view to be same height as scrollview. But main view contains multiple subviews of smaller height

Comment: you said that you need to make the mainview same height as scrollview, if you do this your screen will not be scrolled exactly what is happening now. if you want those view with height 181 to be scrolled inside scrollview then you need to increase the height of the mainview.

Comment: but if you just want to make height same then you just add a constraint equal height to scrollview and remove the center y constraint.

Comment: Yes I actually want that. I want to increase the height of mainView according to the views it contains. But I am not able to increase the height of mainView.  I also want content size of scrollview and height of main view to be equal.

Comment: i got it am changing your code and will give you link of a repo soon.

Comment: Ok. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have changed a little download again.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works fine as the mainView height is now equal to content size of scroll view. But there is one issue that width of subviews are not increasing according to the device, seems like constraints are not working properly. While it is working fine in your code. You can find my code in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GbdFwoUdh5b2xDQzRPcVQtY3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: add those 3 lines just below the initialization of int variable numberOfSubviews.

    width = self.view.frame.size.width * (width / 320.0);
    width_spacer = self.view.frame.size.width * (width_spacer / 320.0);
    height = self.view.frame.size.height * (height / 568.0);

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works fine for me. But constraints I have used programatically are not working properly.

Comment: actually those constraints working. why you are thinking that those constraints not working?

Comment: as my subviews width are not working proportionally.

Comment: actually this behavior is because you are calculating the ratio of the aspect ratio between the fixed 181 or 278 value against the whole width....either you should calculate the aspect ratio between those fixed values against 320 and 568 or you should increase those fixed values to required and then calculate against current device width and height. i did the second one.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I got my mistake.